# Result is maintained in javascript array

Tags: javascript

If I search in an array of objects in javascript, why is the previous result still in memory? I got the following code:

```
function findTasks( date ) {   
   var result = $.grep( tasks[current].tasks, function( task ) {
      return task.date == date;
   });
   return result; 
}
```

When I fire this method and assign it to a variable :

```
var result = findTasks('24-12-2012'); 
// The hardcoded date is for demonstration (it is dynamic in my application)
console.log( result );
```

Then each time I do the `findTasks()` method, my result of the previous search is being maintained. Even when I do the following:

```
function findTasks( date ) {   
    var result = null; // Notice this line
    var result = $.grep( tasks[current].tasks, function( task ) {
       return task.date == date;
    });
    return result; 
}
```

The results are also maintained.

**Edit:**
Each time the findTasks() method fires, the latest results must return. And not the return of the previous method invocations.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Your "question" isn't clear

Comment: So, you want your garbage collector to kick in sooner? Remember that a GC is not required to release objects _as soon_ as they become egligible for collection.

Comment: Could you post the values in the array `tasks[current].tasks` and the different input you use when invoking `findTasks()`?

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net a demo that shows your problem?

Comment: `var result = null;` has (almost) no effect since `result` is `undefined` when the function scope is entered. Also note the accidental redeclaration of `result`. This also doesn't affect the `result` from any previous invocation of the function.

Comment: This is more likely a problem with the array that's passed in or the passing in of the date and the grep always returns the same thing, not js failing to update your result.

Comment: The structure of my application is complex, so i can't demonstrate it. but i resolved my problem. I console.log()'ed the result on a modal show event. When i do the console.log() after that, my result is shown correct.